# Row order in "magic" tables inserted deleted

Tags: sql-server

Using an **instead** **of** trigger on Update, I need to check if the **Primary Key** was changed and if it was, I need to know the value of the old PKL and the value of the new PK, for every row where it was changed. Since, in order to join **inserted** and **deleted** tables I normally use the **Primary Key**, I can't do it anymore. I was thinking about using **cursor** to compare **PK** row-by-row (sth. like Oracle **:new, :old**).

Hence my question is whether rows in **deleted** and **inserted** tables (on update) are always in the same order?

Comment: No - rows in a table have no order that you can "access" via any query. Order is determined by the query that generates your resultset - no order by clause means your rows have an indeterminate order. Your goal, at this point, is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> question is whether rows in deleted and inserted tables (on update) are always in the same order?
>   No, the INSERTED and DELETED virtual tables are not guaranteed to be in the same order.

Your options (in roughly descending order of goodness):

1) Prohibit primary key updates.

2) Prohibit multi-row updates from changing the Primary Key by aborting the transaction in the trigger.

3) Using an Alternate Key to join the tables.